# Idk how to get info from a .dat file and make a single linked list from that using C

Tags: c, file, linked-list

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_LENG 100
#define PAGE_LENG 30


typedef struct pDB {
    char model[MAX_LENG];
    char ram[MAX_LENG];
    char memSpace[MAX_LENG];
    char screenSize[MAX_LENG];
    char price[MAX_LENG];
}phonedb;

struct nod {
    phonedb phone;
    struct nod* next;
};
typedef struct nod node;

node* root, * prev, * cur;

node *newNode(phonedb p)
{
    node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->phone = p;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

void insertAfterCur(phonedb p)
{
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("phonedb.dat", "rb");
    while (fread(&p, sizeof(phonedb), 1, fptr))
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = newNode(p);
            cur = root;
        }
        else
        {
            cur->next = newNode(p);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}


int main()
{
    phonedb p;
    int inp;
    FILE* fptr;
    FILE* fptr2;


    while (1)
    {
        printf("2. Create a list from dat\n");
        printf("3. Print all database\n");
        printf("4. Quit\n");

        scanf("%d", &inp);

        switch (inp)
        {
        case(2):
            insertAfterCur(p);
            break;

        case(3):
            for (cur = root; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
            {
                printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", cur->phone.model, cur->phone.ram, cur->phone.memSpace, cur->phone.screenSize, cur->phone.price);
            }
            break;

        case(4):
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

it only printed out 1 line of infor and the rest are '\n' with the price infor a printed as some strange characters. My phonedb struct has model, ram, memspace, screensize and price which are all strings and node struct contains a phonedb type and a pointer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Problem may or may not be in the code you have shown. It could be in the way the file was written, it could be in the code that does the printing. It could be in the way the insert function was called, it could be in the way `phonedb` was defined, etc.

Comment: You are right. We need a MCVE. `cur` just materialized from somewhere.

Comment: I tried to upload my full code but it says that my cmt is full of code and need more details... my printing function is alright I already tested it and my .dat file was a copy paste from a program I wrote before

Comment: @kaylum how can I show u that example btw

Comment: Read the link. It tells you what to do in detail.

Comment: sorry im still confused if i have to upload those parts that u mentioned before or like I should send the image of the output it prints out

Comment: @kaylum i think the problem is there because of my fread function. cause when I use that while() to fscanf info from a txt file it printed out correctly

Comment: We can't help you with the info you have given. It looks fine or at least the problem is not obvious. Without more of the code and really code we can run then we just can't help you. You are making claims like the write function is fine and the print function is fine. But you are here because you don't know where the error is. So if you can't/won't show the other code there is not much more we can do.

Comment: oh im sr. my bad... im uploading part by part of them right now as its too long too upload all at once

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_LENG 100
#define PAGE_LENG 30


typedef struct pDB {
    char model[MAX_LENG];
    char ram[MAX_LENG];
    char memSpace[MAX_LENG];
    char screenSize[MAX_LENG];
    int price;
}phonedb;

void importDBtext(FILE* fptr, FILE* fptr2);
int lineCount(FILE* fptr);

int main()
{
    phonedb p;
    int inp;
    FILE* fptr;
    FILE* fptr2;


    while (1)
    {
        printf("1. Convert txt to dat\n");
        printf("5. Quit\n");

        scanf("%d", &inp);

        switch (inp)
        {
        case(1):
            fptr = fopen("phonedb.txt", "r");
            fptr2 = fopen("phonedb.dat", "wb+");
            importDBtext(fptr, fptr2);
            fclose(fptr);
            fclose(fptr2);
            break;

        case(5):
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int lineCount(FILE* fptr)
{
    char* c;
    c = malloc(6969 * sizeof(char*));

    int count = 0;
    while (fgets(c, 6969, fptr))
        count++;

    rewind(fptr);
    return count;
}

void importDBtext(FILE* fptr, FILE* fptr2)
{
    phonedb *p;


    p = malloc(lineCount(fptr) * sizeof(phonedb));
    int i = 0;

    while (fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %s %s %d", p[i].model, p[i].ram, p[i].memSpace, p[i].screenSize, &p[i].price) != EOF)
    {


        i++;

    }

    fwrite(p, sizeof(phonedb), i, fptr2);
}
```

Comment: here is how I create my .dat file @kaylum

Comment: I create the dat file in another program and copy paste it to the phonelist program file im working on.

Comment: What is the expected output and actual output?

Comment: LOL i knew why my problem occurs :v I create a .dat file with price has int struct but when i write the phonelist program i defined price as string :v thank you for caring and answering me... so sorry for bothering